# Populating @Html.DropDownList's Text and Value

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a @Html.DropDownList that I need to have it's text and value changed based off of a prior choice.

```
if ($(data.agt.CoAgentMLSAID != null) == "True") {
$("#SelectedAgent").html("{0}, {1}", data.agt.CoAgentLastName,
data.agt.CoAgentFirstName);
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
$document.getElementById("#SelectedAgent").text = ("{0}, {1}", data.agt.CoAgentLastName, data.agt.CoAgentFirstName);
```

instead of the other one above.  Didn't work

And I have this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedAgent", this.Model.OfficeAgents, new { @class = "fl-space2", @id ="SelectedAgent" } )
```

What I'm getting is the default value and not the value of the names based off of the if statement above.  How can I change that?  The default text is in the Model.

I'm not very strong with jQuery, so I'm betting it's something quick.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:
Create view model as below:

```
public class ViewModel{

  public List<SelectListItem> OfficeAgents {get; set}
  public string SelectedAgent {get; set}

  public MyViewModel(){
      OfficeAgents = new List<SelectListItem>();
      SelectedAgent = "ABC"; //default values go here
  }

}
```

Send this view model to ur view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    ViewModel model = new ViewModel ();

   //do query and set agents data to model.OfficeAgents and set default agent data

    model.SelectedAgent = "Agent1";

    //Pass it to the view 
    return ActionResult( model);
}
```

Set ur model to dropdownlist in view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedAgent", this.Model.OfficeAgents, this.Model.SelectedAgent, new { @class = "fl-space2", @id ="SelectedAgent" } )
```